# Rails 4 ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken with multiple subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-4, subdomain

Before let me say that I search google and a lot of posts here at Stackoverflow, but nothing was able to give a solution for my problem. for this, I am creating a new post.

I am creating an application with two sub-domains: account.psantos.dev and app.psantos.dev.

At: `config/initializers/session_store.rb`I have:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_psantos.co.ao_session', domain: 'psantos.dev'
```

And I have the following structure folders:

> - app
>   -- controllers
>   --- app1
>   ---- welcome_controller.rb
>   --- account
>   ---- welcome_controller.rb
>   --views
>   --- layout
>   ---- app1.html.erb
>   ---- account.html.erb
>   --- app1
>   ---- welcome
>   ----- index.html.erb
>   --- account
>   ---- welcome
>   ----- index.html.erb

at: `app/views/layout/app1.html.erb` (http://app1.psantos.dev) I have the following line:

```
<li><%= "Logout", account_sign_out_url, method: :delete %></li>
```

When I  click this Link (that will go to: http://account.psantos.dev), I got the following error:
`ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken at /sign_out
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`

on both layout files (app1.html.erb and account.html.erb) I have this line before <\head > tag :

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

how can I solve this problem?

## Update: relevant log

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-08 12:37:03 +0100 Processing
by APP1::WelcomeController#index as HTML   Parameters:
{"subdomain"=>"app1"}   Rendered app1/welcome/index.html.erb within
layouts/app1 (0.4ms)   [1m[35mEntity Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT 
"entities".* FROM "entities" WHERE "entities"."user_token" = $1 LIMIT
1  [["user_token", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]] Completed 200 OK in 43ms
(Views: 42.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started DELETE "/sign_out" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-08 12:37:05 +0100
Processing by Account::SessionsController#destroy as HTML  
Parameters: {"subdomain"=>"account"} Can't verify CSRF token
authenticity Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (ActiveRecord:
0.0ms)

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken -
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken:   actionpack (4.2.3)
lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:181:in
`handle_unverified_request'   actionpack (4.2.3)
lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:209:in
`handle_unverified_request'   actionpack (4.2.3)
lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:204:in
`verify_authenticity_token'   activesupport (4.2.3)
lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:430:in `block in make_lambda'  
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:143:in `block in
halting_and_conditional'   activesupport (4.2.3)
lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:502:in `block in call'   activesupport
(4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:502:in `call'
```

Comment: Please show us the view code and relevant piece of log file.

Comment: hi @Зелёный, see the log.. I updated the post. Which view you need to show the code?

Comment: try to switch in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` to`protect_from_forgery with: :null_session`  and read about [CSRF](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf) in Rails.

Comment: @Зелёный but this will not open a security hole?

Comment: _To protect against all other forged requests, we introduce a required security token that our site knows but other sites don't know. We include the security token in requests and verify it on the server._

Comment: one way is create own handler with `rescue_from`

Answer (score 1):

Now it's impossible to do :delete request to subdomain.

> There is an vulnerability in jquery-ujs and jquery-rails that can be used to bypass CSP protections and allows attackers to send CSRF tokens to attacker domains. This vulnerability has been assigned the CVE identifier CVE-2015-1840. Versions Affected: All. Not affected: Applications which don't use jquery-ujs or jquery-rails. Fixed Versions: jquery-rails versions 4.0.4 and 3.1.3 and jquery-ujs 1.0.4. Impact ------ In the scenario where an attacker might be able to control the href attribute of an anchor tag or the action attribute of a form tag that will trigger a POST action, the attacker can set the href or action to " https://attacker.com" (note the leading space) that will be passed to JQuery, who will see this as a same origin request, and send the user's CSRF token to the attacker domain.

This is [commit](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/commit/96561a2ac0fab58e3e248458e19003e09f106ec4) to jquery-ujs:
[image: image with diff code in jquery-ugs]

You can read more [here](http://blog.honeybadger.io/understanding-the-rails-jquery-csrf-vulnerability-cve-2015-1840/)

Answer (score 0):

I have a front-end and a rails back-end api in different subdomains, the code bellow works for me:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception, unless: :same_origin?
  before_action :verify_authenticity_token, unless: :same_origin

  private

  def same_origin?
    request.host == Rails.application.config.hosts.first
  end
end
```